# Facebook flash game data store method

Tags: database, flash, facebook, save, store

Hy, i am currently working on a facebook game,the game is good and ready except the storing part!How do you suggest i should store my data!I will use a database, but what is the best way to get data from facebook and into my database trough flash?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add more detail? Is the data per-user, or specific to the game and common to all users? Does the data need to be accessible only by game clients, or by something like a backend server as well? Is it just something like high scores?

Answer (score 0):

u can use database, by using get and set method.

**Example:**

**Set**: set the user data into database ( www.mysite.com/fb/game/store.ashx?uid=**&score=**&level=__; )

*return: success or failed*

**Get**: get the user data from database ( www.mysite.com/fb/game/getUserData.ashx?uid=__; )

*return: user data*